# Arc degree in the circumference

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

In this image, $MN \parallel AT$, $CD=DA$ and $\angle PDT=90º$ then arc $NP$=?
[image]

I don't know how to apply the angle theorems inside this circle. I tried calling $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ the arcs $CM$, $MB$ and $PT$ respectively, and then applying equation systems, but it didn't work.

Any hints?

Comment: what do you want to find length of arc?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $DT$ is pependicular bisector for segment $AC$.

Since $$\angle NMT = \angle MTA = \angle MTA$$ we see that chord $CM$ and $NT$ are equal. So $CMTN$ is trapezoid and so $CN||MT$ and thus $PC\bot CN$, so $\angle NC P = 90^{\circ}$

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but isn't $\overparen{\rm CM}+\overparen{\rm PT}=180º$ according to secant theorem? Also $\overparen{\rm PT}>\overparen{\rm PN}$

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to tell me.

Comment: if $m\angle{NCP}=90º$ then $\overparen{\rm PN}=180º$

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to say.